# Error in live mp3 ffmpeg encoder using python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ffmpeg, subprocess

I have a code like below. i want to record  sound and convert each wav frame to mp3 format in
real time using ffmpeg

```
import pyaudio,sys
import subprocess
command = ['ffmpeg', '-y','-f','wav' , '-i', '-', '-f', 'mp3', '-']
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 1024*10
RECORD_SECONDS = 2
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)


mp3 = open("mp3.mp3",'wb')
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    recording_mp3, errordata = process.communicate(data)
    mp3.write(recording_mp3)
```

Now my code producing error

**pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input**

My ffmpeg and audio recording working fine. 
How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: If it's really stuck at line 4, why did you include the rest of the file?

Comment: sorry i mean error producing from subprocess

Comment: Check with ffmpeg authors how ffmpeg can process piped output

Comment: it is possible
i can convert wav to mp3 like this     cat wavfile.wav | ffmpeg -y -f wav -i - -f mp3 - >mp3file.mp3

Comment: It might be that `communicate` doesn't work with the implicit `universal_newlines` option. See the box about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) (search for "universal_newlines"): "Also, the newlines attribute of the file objects `stdout`, `stdin` and `stderr` are not updated by the communicate() method." You might have to use `stdout.write()` instead of `communicate`.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do without calling subprocesses ? I'm looking for the same kind of inline compression and portability.